# Random different values in Java and Matlab wavread?

Tags: java, matlab, arrays

I am reading wave files in my java program. The right channel audio has half the sample which happens to be 445440 samples (double amplitude values). Everything is working fine except for some significant differences in the values I am reading in Matlab. What's bugging me is that most of the values are identical (in my program and Matlab), but when I averaged all the elements, the values are quite far apart:
in Matlab I got: 1.4581E*-05, and my program: -44567.3253
So I started checking out values until I found a different value at the 166th element!
Matlab has     `-6.10351562500000e-05` and I have     `2.0`! (the value before and after are this are identical).
This is quite frustrating as only few elements in the first 300 elements differed! As you can imagine, I cannot physically go through all 445440 elements to understand the pattern.
I don't even know where to start looking for the issue. So taking a chance by asking all the brilliant minds out there. Here's my code if it helps:

```
public double[] getAmplitudes(Boolean asArrayOfDouble){

    //bytesInASample is 2 (16-bit little endian);
    int numOfSamples = data.length / bytesInASample ;
    double[] amplitudes = new double[numOfSamples];

    int pointer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
        double ampValue= 0;
        for (int byteNumber = 0; byteNumber < bytesPerSample; byteNumber ++) {
            ampValue+= (double) ((data[pointer ++] & 0xFF) << (byteNumber  * 8))/32767.0;

        }
        amplitudes[i] = ampValue;
    }
    return amplitudes;
}
```

After this, I am simply reading the right channel data by using the following code:

```
double[] rightChannelData = new double[data.length/2];
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length/2; i++)
    { 
        rightChannelData [i] =  data[2*i+1];
        }
```

I know this might be a hard question to answer without seeing the actual program and it's output in contrast to the Matlab output. So do let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: What is the type of array `data` ?

Comment: @ortis It's a byte array

Comment: I have initialized it with the inputstream data, i.e. `byte[] data = new byte[inputstream.available()];` I have no issues getting the data, just don't know why it varies big time with Matlab at certain points

Comment: Did you check whether or not sample were signed ?

Comment: Not really. Do I need to? @ortis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are masking all bytes with the term `data[pointer ++] & 0xFF` creating all-unsigned values. For values consisting of two bytes you are creating `int` values between `0` and `65536` which, after dividing by `32767.0`, yield to values between `0.0` and `2.0` whereas Matlab using signed interpretation produces values in the range `-1.0` and `1.0`.

To illustrate this:

The `short` value `0xFFFE`, interpreted as signed value is `-2`, and the division is `-2/32768.0` produces `-6.10351562500000e-05` while interpreted as unsigned is `65534` and `65534/32767.0` produces `2.0`.

<sup>(Note that the negative value was divided by the absolute value of `Short.MIN_VALUE` rather than `Short.MAX_VALUE`…)</sup>

It’s not clear how you could calculate an average of `-44567.3253` from that. Even for your unsigned values (between `0.0` and `2.0`) that is way off.

After all, you are better off not doing everything manually:

```
ShortBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
               .asShortBuffer();
int numOfSamples = buf.remaining();
double[] amplitudes = new double[numOfSamples];
for (int i = 0; i < numOfSamples; i++) {
    amplitudes[i] = buf.get() * (1.0/32768.0);
}
return amplitudes;
```

Since I don’t know how Matlab does the normalization I cannot guaranty that the values are the same. It’s possible that the loop body has to look like this instead:

```
    final short s = buf.get();
    amplitudes[i] = s * (s<0? (1.0/32768.0): (1.0/32767));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes some sense now. Though it will take more time for me to fully understand. I divided `ampValue` with `maxAmplitude = 1 << (w.getHeader().getBitsPerSample() - 1)`. Now the values are similar.

Comment: However, do you by any chance know how to do this operation on a double: if (!signed) {`maxAmplitude <<=1;}`.  It says the operator `<<=` is undefined for type double?

Comment: hey, nevermind! Replace the code with you `ShortBuffer` code and it's working like magic! Now I have same values as Matlab. Cheers!

Comment: @Nate Raswar: I’m glad that it helped. Just for completeness: `x <<= 1 ` is the same as `x *= 2 `. The latter works with `double` too.